# Creating a global multi dimensional array Swift 4

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I am trying to save data "productID" as Int, "quantity" as Int, "price" as Double in a global array in swift 4.

Each productID key should be containing "quantity" and "price" columns.

```
productID - quantity - price
----------------------------
1           3         1.00
```

How can I create an array like this in a global class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep products as structures:

```
struct Product {
  let id: Int
  let quantity: Int
  let price: Double
}
```

then define array:

```
internal static var productArray = [Product]()
```

and add your products.

```
let product = Product(id: 1, quantity: 99, price: 1.99)
productArray.append(product)
```

`internal static` prefix lets you to reach the array throughout the app. However, I don't think you want to use this pattern in your app.

Comment: Using a struct is a good solution. I did not know about the internal modifier. +1